# I need help Template Django "for" "if"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I need to search for a particular object with the `if` conditions, in case nothing is found, the `else` is executed, the problem with this is that the `else` is executed for each object in the array, and I need it to only be executed after having traversed the entire array and the if condition has not been met,  I have 4 objects in that array

```
                          {% for horario in horarios %}
                            <!--Lunes-->
                             {% if horario.dia == 'Lunes'  and horario.hora_inicio == '8:00' %}                                        
                                <td> Asignatura: {{horario.id_asignatura.nombre}}<br>
                                    Profesor: {{horario.rut_profesor.p_nombre}} {{horario.rut_profesor.ap_paterno}}<br>
                                    Sala: {{horario.id_sala.id_sala}}
                                </td>
                             {% else %}
                                <td>Horario no disponible</td>
                             {% endif %}
                            
                                
                           {% endfor %}
```

[how I want it to look with the `else`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Izq.png)

[what it actually looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJbJ0.png)

Comment: Share your view...

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
                       {% for horario in horarios %}
                        <!--Lunes-->
                         {% if horario.dia == 'Lunes'  and horario.hora_inicio == '8:00' %}                                        
                            <td> Asignatura: {{horario.id_asignatura.nombre}}<br>
                                Profesor: {{horario.rut_profesor.p_nombre}} {{horario.rut_profesor.ap_paterno}}<br>
                                Sala: {{horario.id_sala.id_sala}}
                            </td>
                         {% endif%}
                         {% empty %}
                            <td>Horario no disponible</td> 
                       {% endfor %}
```

Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

Comment: doesn't show anything

Comment: if your list is empty it must show <td>Horario no disponible</td> .
if list exist items it will go in loop of condition and print .
if you have only this (single if) then you must filter data before sending to html page it wont need to be here